# Is it possible to use wikitude and indoorAtlas in an existing cordova application that detects ibeacons?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, wikitude, indoor-positioning-system

My application as of now detects any iBeacons around to notify the customer in a store about the new arrivals and discounts....now i want the customer if interested to be navigated to that particular aisle or wherever that product is.
so my question is can we use indoorAtlas for positioning purpose and wikitude to introduce augmented reality into my app.

Comment: As long as both plugins can coexist at the same time (build time), it should be possible to use both. The Wikitude plugin has a function called 'callJavaScript' which you can use to pass some data (JSON format) into there so called `Architect World`.

Answer (score 0):

IndoorAtlas has Cordova: http://docs.indooratlas.com/cordova/

You can also use beacons with IndoorAtlas by using the setLocation and start using IA positioning from that point.